# How to assign attributes to a Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript

So I'm in the process of making a medieval-themed game, and I need to have a system of equipping combinations of armor, weapons, and shields to different types of troops. I used to have a system that showed how many of any possible combination I had, but then it was hard to sift through the hundred combinations to see how many troops you have. So, I've decided to have a show all troops menu, but each troop needs to have three slots only: armor, weapon, and shield. As the troops start off as just

```
    var basicTroopAmount = 0;
```

and as you recruit them the amount goes up. I just am asking if anyone knows a better way that each troop is "personalized" in the sense that each one can be equipped with different sets of armor and weapons, and how to tell the code that the armor variables are armor and cannot go in the weapon slot and that multiple armors cannot go into one slot. I know this question is pretty loaded, but if anyone has any input that would help a ton!

Comment: Use objects, with private properties and public mutators.

Comment: You want to store your troops as *objects* inside an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object and store all the properties and methods you need.

```
function Troop(armor, weapon, shield) {
            var armor = armor;
            var weapon = weapon;
            var shield = shield;

            this.getTroopDetails = function() {
                console.log("Armour -> " + armor + ", Weapon -> " + weapon + ", Shield -> " + shield);
            }
        }
```

Create new Troop objects as you wish and maintain them in an Array:

```
        var Troop1 = new Troop("Iron","Sword","Round");
        Troop1.getTroopDetails(); //Prints Armour -> Iron, Weapon -> Sword, Shield -> Round

        var Troop2 = new Troop("Bombsuit","Lance","Square");
        Troop2.getTroopDetails(); //Prints Armour -> Bombsuit, Weapon -> Lance, Shield -> Square

        var TroopList = [];
        TroopList.push(Troop1);
        TroopList.push(Troop2);
        console.log(TroopList);
```

UPDATE:
In your HTML, add the following code to your button. I am passing hardcoded values to the addTroop function, you can pass user entered values:

```
<button type="button" onClick="TroopManager.addTroop('Iron','Sword','Round')">Add Troop</button>
```

In your JavaScript, implement the function:

```
var TroopManager = {
          myTroopArray : [],

          addTroop : function(armor, weapon, shield) {
            var Troop1 = new Troop(armor, weapon, shield);
            this.myTroopArray.push(Troop1);
            console.log("A new Troop has been added.")
            this.printTroops();
          },

          printTroops : function() {
            for(i=0;i<this.myTroopArray.length;i++) {
                console.log(this.myTroopArray[i].getTroopDetails());
            }

          }
        }
```

Comment: How would you suggest going about adding these Troop variables? I want it to be that as you click the training button one appears, so is there a way to generate new Objects that way?

Comment: Invoke a function on 'OnClick' event of the button and add your processing into that.  Please check the updated answer.